# How to structure a sql query to get number of mutual friends between users?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, mysqli

I am busy trying to create a query that returns the number of mutual friends between users in a userlist. I have tried a few but they haven't been working as I had hoped, here is one of the queries I have tried

```
query("SELECT * FROM userlist WHERE userid = '$userid' AND status ='friend' AND friendid != '$userid' ");
```

the sql table below renders the relationships between users.

```
userid | friendid | type | status |
-----------------------------------
1      |2         | buddy | friend |
-----------------------------------
1      |3         | buddy | friend |
-----------------------------------
2      |3         | buddy | friend |
-----------------------------------
3      |2         | buddy | friend |
-----------------------------------
4      |2         | buddy | friend |
-----------------------------------
3      |1         | buddy | friend |
-----------------------------------
2      |4         | buddy | friend |
------------------------------------
```

How would I structure a query to find the number of mutual friends between `userid 4` and `userid 1`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will help, Please note that, here i do not have used condition of "status", you can modify this query as per your requirement.

```
SELECT count(*) FROM userlist as a 
INNER JOIN  userlist as b 
ON(b.friendid=a.friendid and  b.userid=4 and b.friendid!=1)
WHERE a.userid=1 and b.friendid!=4
```

This will return number of mutual friends.

As per your data this will give result 1 as for user ID 1 and 4 there is only one mutual friend 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select friendid
FROM userlist as F
WHERE userid = 1

Select friendid
FROM userlist as S
WHERE userid = 4

Select Distinct *
From F Join S
ON F.friendid = S.friendid
```

Would give you only the mutual friends of 1 and 4.

Comment: would that be a part of just one query? eg : `query("Select friendid
FROM userlist as F
WHERE userid = 1

Select friendid
FROM userlist as S
WHERE userid = 4

Select Distinct *
From F Join S
ON F.friendid = S.friendid");`or is that 3 different queries?

Comment: or would I use `UNION`

Comment: Use `JOIN` (e.g. equi-join), instead of `UNION`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Distinct a.friendid as mutual_friend
FROM user_list AS a
JOIN user_list b ON a.friendid = b.friendid
WHERE (a.userid =1 or a.friendid=1)
AND (b.userid =2 or b.friendid=2)
```

It would give you the Mutual friends id

Answer (score 0):

I made a test Table upon your query and made up a query which will show ids of two friends and no of mutual friends between them.

```
    SELECT
    a.ID as Person1, b.ID as Person2, COUNT(a.FriendID) as NoOfMutualFriends 
    FROM
    Friends a INNER JOIN Friends b 
    ON a.FriendID = b.FriendID 
    WHERE a.ID <> b.ID     //other filters can be used here
    GROUP BY a.ID, b.ID 
    ORDER BY a.ID
```

Ask if any Doubts ;)